# How can I move the screen using SDL2, C++?

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a window with a width of 260 pixels. By using the DrawSurface function I can put an image on the position which is not visible on the screen, for example (500, 10). Now I want to move the screen (by pressing the button) to the point where is the image. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how accurate or up-to-date [this article](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson21/index.php) is but it gives a lot of starting code for implementing a makeshift camera using an SDL_Rect variable. In your case, you would modify the x and y variables of the camera object and use the apply_surface() method to show textures relative to the camera's position.